# Why php date("t", 1604188800) return 16?

Tags: php, date

I have a problem, for some reason

> date("t", 1604188800)

returns 16

though in the documentation writes that date("t") returns from 28 to 31

Comment: What version of PHP you use ?

Comment: `echo date("t", 1604188800);` outputs 30, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @kerbh0lz in my case it returns 31, what the PHP version you use ?

Comment: I can't reproduce https://3v4l.org/DEnfD

Comment: @wajdi_jurry Oh ;) Using 7.4.

Comment: my php version 7.1-x64

Comment: Sorry, the code was overlooked, everything is fine, the date("t") function works fine

Comment: @ЮраПляцик Can you state what the problem was that you got 16?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to get the number of days in a month, you should provide most accurate input.

Example:

```
<?php

echo date("t", strtotime("October"));  // 31
```

Comment: Why would it make any difference how you get the timestamp? How would this be more "accurate"?

Comment: PHP calculates dates and timestamps depending on the input, that's why:
`date("t", 1604188800)` returns 30 while `date("t", strtotime("October"))` returns 31 even if that two timestamps refer to the same month

Comment: No, the reason for the difference is that is that 1604188800 is November 1st, while you're asking for October.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please try this and provide the result:
`date("Y-m-d G:i:s", 1604188800)`

Comment: Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/bI8Ln And also, the OP didn't actually get 30, they said they got 16, which doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Maybe it is related to the zone where are you in ?
https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18d038ca720032eab7aa28635978adf94193262a
I got 31th of October at 17:00:00

Comment: unixtimestamp.com says _"1604188800 Is equivalent to: 11/01/2020 @ 12:00am (UTC)_"